# How to add a URL for an image attribute type? / Akeneo 2.*

Tags: akeneo

*How to add a URL for an image attribute type ?*

The import process of Akeneo looks for a folder **files/** at the level of the execution of the import. How to change this by searching through the URL put in the product file?

*My akeneo error:*

> Property "img_1" expects a valid pathname as data,
>   "data/import/http://mywebsite.de/Documents/PHOTO/DMIM_BD.jpg"
>   given.)

*My order to run the import product:*

```
bin/console akeneo:batch:job csv_product_import -c "{\"filePath\": \"/custom/path/to/product.xlsx\"}" --env=prod
```